# SQL query to get highest values in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with the following information:

```
ID          Name        Value       
===         =====       =======
1           apple       5
2           green       10
3           orange      1
4           blue        0
5           fish        3
6           lettuce     2
7           cabbage     4
8           computer    1
9           car     0
10          sport       9
11          racing      15
```

I want to be able to only pull 3 highest value records in this table. So for example i would want to pull the following in that order.

```
11          racing      15
2           green       10
10          sport       9
```

I know i can use ORDER BY to order them by value so it gives me the highest first. But how would i query to only get those records?

Comment: Add Limit 3 to end of query

Comment: is this mysql or sql-server?

Comment: Then why do you have the sql-server tag?

Comment: i added it by mistake, i didn't know how to take it off once i posted

Answer (score 5):

You can do as

```
select * from your_table order by Value desc limit 3
```

Comment: how would i be able to asjust if, i had 5 rows and only 1 had a value of 10 and the last 4 had a value 0, can i automatically adjust the order by to a different field?

Comment: @BradHazelnut - just add more on the end of the order by list.

Comment: If you have one row as 10 and rest all as 0 then 10 comes first followed by the rest. But you can customize the order value but you will need to use case or field() to do this.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server

```
SELECT TOP 3 * FROM tablename order by Value DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can ORDER BY multiple columns. If I'm interpreting your request, you could ORDER BY VALUE DESC, NAME. So the result with the 10 would still be first, followed by all those with 0, ordered alphabetically by name.