# How to get maximum 2 values in column in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

For example

```
1
10
8
9
5
```

I should find maximum of two values in given column as answer is 10 and 9 in sql query

Comment: If there are two rows with the value 5, do you want 5 and 5 returned, or 5 and 4?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL query to get highest values in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24458356/sql-query-to-get-highest-values-in-a-table)

Comment: i want to find two highest marks from column

Answer (score 8):

You can use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select col
from t
order by col desc
limit 2;
```

If the column can have duplicates, you an use `select distinct col`.

Comment: No if column contains 1,13,14,3,4,16 then maximum values will be 14 and 16